# Change the default connection router in graphiti?

Tags: javascript, graphiti-js

When you connect two ports in graphiti (by mouse dragging) a default connection router is used. How do I change this to let's say a bezierConnectionRouter ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use the following at the beginning of your code 
draw2d.Connection.DEFAULT_ROUTER = new draw2d.layout.connection.ManhattanBridgedConnectionRouter(); (or other types of routers you need)